# Cannot log in to Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I'm facing a problem with log in on Stack Overflow. My account (my email address) is not recognized anymore. My username is jmcollin92, I'm sure of my email address, i use before, but the log in on stack exchange always tells me "No account with this email found".

Any clues (I would like to get my account back ...) and not restart from scratch.

The only think different is that I've change my PC. I can't try anymore with the old one. I read this but without success : Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have a Stack Exchange OpenID associated with your profile. It looks like you used Google credentials instead. I can't give you more detail than that in a public answer.

Plug your email address into the [account recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) page and that should help get you going. If it doesn't, email us with the email address you used on your old account and we'll go from there.